How configure some modifier key to draw line strictly horizontal (hold Y) or vertical (hold X)?
I have Wacom tablet (CTL-6100) and want to be able to easily draw strictly horizontal or vertical lines (to draw electrical schemes).
Is there some modifier / config that hold/freeze X coordinate and draw only Y coordinate to draw strictly vertical line or vice versa (freeze Y coordinate and draw only X coordinate to draw strictly horizontal line)?
Thanks
